# BufferOverflowException when generating Javadoc?

Tags: exception, unicode, javadoc, buffer-overflow

Has anybody ever had problems with the javadoc tool causing a java.nio.BufferOverflowException?

I'm trying to generate Javadoc for code with Japanese comments (charset MS932). I think that might be related. Does anybody know of a workaround for this problem?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:495)
at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.put(HeapCharBuffer.java:145)
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DefaultFileManager.decode(DefaultFileManager.java:830)
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DefaultFileManager.access$300(DefaultFileManager.java:76)
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DefaultFileManager$RegularFileObject.getCharContent(DefaultFileManager.java:1353)
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.DefaultFileManager$RegularFileObject.getCharContent(DefaultFileManager.java:1252)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSource(JavaCompiler.java:483)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:550)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:541)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.JavadocTool.getRootDocImpl(JavadocTool.java:126)at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:330)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is character encoding is not set up right.